# trim mapping columns in JPA

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, mapping

I am having two tables namely employee and department. Both tables are mapped with column department code. I am using @OneToOne relationship between this. But my query is getting failed due to white spaces in department code.

```
@Table(name = "EMP_MASTER")
public class Employee{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idcode")
    private String idcode;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPT_CD", referencedColumnName = "DEPT_CD")
    private Department dept;
   
    //some more columns
}


@Table(name = "DEPT_MASTER")
public class Department{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPT_CD")
    private String deptCode;
    
    //some more columns
}
```

In repository I am using simple query method.

```
Optional<Employee> findByIdcodeIs(String idcode);
```

The query is also perfect; but this join is not working correctly.

```
left outer join
     dept_master deptmaster1_
          on employee0_.dept_cd=deptmaster1_.dept_cd
```

instead of this, if I change below query at database level using **TRIM()** then it gives me correct result.

```
left outer join
     dept_master deptmaster1_
          on TRIM(employee0_.dept_cd)=TRIM(deptmaster1_.dept_cd)
```

So is there any way to apply trim on mapping level?

Answer (score 0):

To change values at mapping level, you could try JPA aAttribute converter. And then apply to mapping field.

Example:
Mapping:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "DEPT_CD")
@Convert(converter = TrimConverter.class)
private String deptCode;
```

Converter:

```
public class TrimConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String value) {
        return value.trim();
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return value.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Convert` does not work with `@JoinColumn` or `@Id` annotations

Answer (score 0):

I have created view of table by applying trim on those columns. This fixed my problem.
I know this is not proper solution. Will looking forward for more answers.

Comment: Did you found any other solution ? I have the same issue and i would like to haven't to create view. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Julien did you manage to find another solution?